# Viewpager Adapter does not reuse views appropriately

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I had do the following code, but the views that offscreen seems does not been recycle appropriately.

assume I have all 60 views to let ViewPager to show, it's display correctly, but it doesn't reuse the views, while I swipe to the tail of ArrayList, the views in preceding still not recycle (I guess it because of I swipe to the rightmost, then swipe to the left again, no sign of reloading)

I've search a lot articles, but all alike what I did below, not sure where's the point.
(here's what I actually did)

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
    ArrayList<View> viewList =  new ArrayList<View>();

    public MyPagerAdapter(ArrayList<View> list) {
        this.viewList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return viewList.size();
}

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = viewList.get(position);
        container.addView(view);
        return view;  
    }


    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object view) {
        container.removeView((View)view);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == (View)object;
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {

    }


    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0) {

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two adapters i.e. `PagerAdapter & FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

PagerAdapter saves pages/views in stack and is used where total number of pages used are lesser in number.
On the other hand if the number of pages/views are more then it is recommended to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter because it does not save save views/pages in stack but creates them during runtime. FragmentStatePagerAdapter Recycles your views/pages.

I recommend to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: I search "StatePagerAdapter" on Android Dev documentation, there seem has no kind of class, but "FragmentStatePagerAdapter"
I'd follow the instruction, but in the part of pagerAdapter = new MyStatePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), viewList); 
the getFragmentManager() return different fm back, or is there has another "StatePagerAdapter"?